# NVIDIA cuDNN installation in ubuntu20.04 docker container

Tags: ubuntu, dockerfile, cudnn

I tried to install NVIDIA cuDNN 8.3.2 following the [official guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html#package-manager-ubuntu-install) in Dockerfile:

```
ENV OS=ubuntu2004

RUN wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/${OS}/x86_64/cuda-${OS}.pin

RUN mv cuda-${OS}.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
RUN apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/${OS}/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
RUN add-apt-repository "deb https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/${OS}/x86_64/ /"
RUN apt-get update

ENV cudnn_version=8.3.2.1
ENV cuda_version=cuda11.5

RUN apt-get install libcudnn8=${cudnn_version}-1+${cuda_version}
RUN apt-get install libcudnn8-dev=${cudnn_version}-1+${cuda_version}
```

and I am getting the error:
`E: Version '8.3.2.1-1+cuda11.5' for 'libcudnn8' was not found The command '/bin/bash -o pipefail -c apt-get install libcudnn8=${cudnn_version}-1+${cuda_version}' returned a non-zero code: 100`

I visited recommended [support matrix](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/archives/cudnn-832/support-matrix/index.html) for versions compatibility, but unfortunately didn't find appropriate instructions. Does anybody know which `cudnn` and `cuda` versions are needed here? Is there a link to REPOs where I can see available packages, [like this one](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/)?

Comment: The current versions are visible on the NVIDIA registered developer site

Answer (score 4):

I found necessary repos in Internet on official sites for developers:

`cuda` repos for different OS: https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/

`libcudnn8` repos for different `cuda` versions:
https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/

onnx execution providers compatibility matrix for `cuda` and `cuDNN`: https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/execution-providers/CUDA-ExecutionProvider.html

So, in my case the answer was:

```
ENV cudnn_version=8.2.4.15
ENV cuda_version=cuda11.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, using @Alexander provided link for [cuda - cudnn compatibility](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/):

if you search for *libcudnn* you can see that for your case (and taking into consideration the choices you made about cuda and libcudnn versions) are 4:
[image]

So, the following combination should work:

```
ENV cudnn_version=8.3.2.44
ENV cuda_version=cuda11.5
```

I placed the closer to the version you provided but I guess other options will work also.